# How to grant permission to clear specific Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to create a role that can clear past Airflow DAG execution in specific DAG.
I have already found that User role has

- `can delete on DAG Runs`
- `can delete on DAGs`

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/delete_dag_run
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_clear_task_instances

But I assume that this permission can delete all DAGs. Which permission should I grant to clear past DAG execution for specific DAG?

Comment: Try the permission combo of  `DAG:<specific_dag>.can_edit`, `DAG Runs.can_read` and `Task Instances.can_edit`. Thats a variation of the combo in [this table](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html#dag-level-permissions) for the `/dags/{dag_id}/clearTaskInstances` endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
DAG:<specific_dag>.can_edit
DAG Runs.can_read
DAG Runs.can_edit
DAG Runs.can_delete
Task Instances.can_read
Task Instances.can_edit
Task Instances.can_delete
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To grant permission to clear past Airflow DAG execution in a specific DAG, you need to grant the following permission:

```
DAG:<DAG_ID>:can_clear
```

This permission allows users to clear past DAG runs for the specified DAG. For example, to grant this permission to a user named alice for the DAG named my_dag, you would run the following command:

```
airflow permissions grant DAG:my_dag:can_clear alice
```